# jQuery selectors performance

Tags: jquery, performance, css-selectors, children

I know I'm just being OCD about a few milliseconds worth of performance time, but I was just wondering why the following is true for me. It seems goes against my logic.

I currently have a div that has fades out the image inside on hover:

```
$('div.someclass').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('img').fadeOut(function(){
        // do something
    });
}, function() {
    // do something
});
```

After some testing, (looping through selectors 1000 times, taking the average of 9 tests) I have used 3 different selectors and concluded that the speed is in this order:

1. `$(this).children('img')` runs the fastest -avg about 400ms;
2. `$('img', this)` - avg about 900ms; and
3. `$(this).find('img')` runs the slowest - avg about 1000ms

This goes against the logic that having two function calls would be slower than one. Plus, I have read that internally, jQuery converts the second case to the third case so would the third case be slower?.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference between `$(this).find('img')` and `$(this).children('img')` is that the `children` function only looks for *direct* `<img>` descendants, while the `find` function finds any `<img>` element anywhere in the DOM hierarchy below `$(this)`. That's why `children` is faster.

`$(this).children('img')`:

```
<h1>                           <!-- Is this img? Nope! -->
    <img alt="" src="..." />   <!-- Never checked. -->
    <span>Bla bla</span>       <!-- Never checked. -->
</h1>
<a href="#">                   <!-- Is this img? Nope! -->
    <img alt="" src="..." />   <!-- Never checked. -->
</a>
<img alt="" src="..." />       <!-- Is this img? Yeah, return it! -->
```

`$(this).find('img')`:

```
<h1>                           <!-- Is this img? Nope! -->
    <img alt="" src="..." />   <!-- Is this img? Yeah, return it! -->
    <span>Bla bla</span>       <!-- Is this img? Nope! -->
</h1>
<a href="#">                   <!-- Is this img? Nope! -->
    <img alt="" src="..." />   <!-- Is this img? Yeah, return it! -->
</a>
<img alt="" src="..." />       <!-- Is this img? Yeah, return it! -->
```

As you can see, there are three elements that won't be checked when using `children`, thus increasing performance.

Comment: Also want to point out that $('img', this) isn't necessarily one function call either, as the conversion process mentioned could call any number of functions as well.

Comment: Well, counting the number of function calls when using jQuery is pointless, because internally, it's calling anywhere between tens to hundreds of functions while processing a selector.